# Data not being fetched from firebase database swift 4

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift4

I'm simply trying to show how far away the user is from the location but I can't seem to get anything being printed to my console. If I place the code in the viewDidLoad and manually put in the coordinates for "postLocations"
I get the distance but I can't seem to get anything printed with the code I have currently.

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let userLocation: CLLocation = locations[0] as CLLocation

    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("posts")
    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] else { return }

        guard let latitude = dictionary["latitude"] as? Double else { return }
        guard let longitude = dictionary["longitude"] as? Double else { return }

        let currentLocation = Coordinate(long: userLocation.coordinate.longitude, lat: userLocation.coordinate.latitude)
        let postLocations = Coordinate(long: longitude, lat: latitude)

        if currentLocation.distance(to: postLocations) <= 100 {
            print("You are \(currentLocation.distance(to: postLocations)) away from posts")
        } else {
            print("No posts in area")
        }

    }) { (error) in
        print("There was an error getting posts", error)
    }

    }
```

[image: Firebase Database]

Comment: Is this method was called `didUpdateLocations`?

Comment: Yeah it's being called

Comment: Check what's in `snapshot.value` maybe your 'guard` returned, like the type isn't `[String: AnyObject]`, maybe try `[String: Any]`, see what happens.

Comment: Are you trying to get the distance between your current location to the user location in the firebase? If you have solved your issue ignore this.

Comment: I'm trying to get the distance between your current location and the post location @GregoryWilsonPullyattu

Comment: when I print out snapshot.value I get all the posts in the console is there a way to maybe condense this down to just print out the coordinates?, I also changed [String: AnyObject] to [String: Any] and got the same result.  @WilliamHu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code in the `viewDidLoad` and check the print statement in the console whether the latitude and longitude is printed.

```
func fetchUserLocation() {
     let ref = Database.database().reference().child("posts")
     ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
     guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] else { return }
     guard let latitude = dictionary["latitude"] as? String else { return }
     guard let longitude = dictionary["longitude"] as? String else { return }
     print("lat: \(latitude), lon: \(longitude)")
   }) { (error) in
    print("There was an error getting posts", error)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call the Firebase observer in the  `didUpdateLocations`.
You should call the Firebase observer in the `viewDidLoad` so that you can fetch the user location from the Firebase Databse. After the observer observe the user location, you need to fetch the current location so that you can compare the 2 locations. Just try this.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Would you be able to show me an example?

Comment: can you call the firebase observer in the viewdidload

Answer (score 0):

On `viewDidLoad()` try accessing Firebase Database by calling this:

```
func getFirebaseUserLocation() {
    let ref = Database.reference(withPath: "posts")
    ref.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        for child in snapshot.children {
            if let postSnapshots = child as? DataSnapshot  { 
                for postSnapshot in postSnapshots.children {
                    guard let postDictionary = postSnapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }
                    guard let latitude = postDictionary["latitude"] as? String, let longitude = postDictionary["longitude"] as? String else { return } 
                    print(latitude, longitude)
                    // here you can access your latitude and longitude as Strings from Firebase Database
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: for some reason I'm not getting the latitude and longitude being printed out still. Even when I place that code into my `viewDidLoad()`

Comment: I think the latitude and longitude may be being returned